# how to build a single module from Android AOSP code base

Tags: android, android-source

I am using the AOSP build environment from aws, which is essentially a AOSP checkout on a EC2 (my guess).

- at the AOSP root level, i could run *>m* to build everything successfully.
- at module level, i could run **>mma** to build the module with all the dependencies successfully.
- however, if i were to run *>mm* at the module folder, it fails.

for example, if i tried to build the Contact apps,

```
    ubuntu@ip-172-31-37-80:~/aosp/oreo/packages/apps/Contacts$ mm
    make: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/aosp/oreo'
    ============================================
    PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
    PLATFORM_VERSION=8.0.0
    TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_arm
    TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
    TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
    TARGET_ARCH=arm
    TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
    TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
    HOST_ARCH=x86_64
    HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
    HOST_OS=linux
    HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-4.15.0-1056-aws-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic
    HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
    HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
    HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
    HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
    BUILD_ID=OPD1.170816.025
    OUT_DIR=out
    ============================================
    [38/38] bootstrap out/soong/.minibootstrap/build.ninja.in
    [1/2] out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/minibp out/soong/.minibootstrap/build.ninja.in
    [4/4] out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/minibp out/soong/.bootstrap/build.ninja
    [791/792] glob test/vts/utils/native/trace_processor/Android.bp
    [47/47] out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build out/soong/build.ninja
    out/build-aosp_arm-packages_apps_Contacts_Android.mk.ninja is missing, regenerating...
    test/vts/tools/build/tasks/vts_package.mk:222: warning: FindEmulator: cd: vendor/google_vts/testcases: No such file or directory
    test/vts/tools/build/tasks/vts_package.mk:222: warning: FindEmulator: cd: vendor/google_vts/testcases: No such file or directory
    test/vts/tools/build/tasks/vts_package.mk:222: warning: FindEmulator: cd: vendor/google_vts/testcases: No such file or directory
    [ 99% 1301/1302] glob vendor/*/*/Android.bp
    ninja: error: 'out/host/linux-x86/bin/aapt', needed by 'out/target/product/generic/obj/APPS/Contacts_intermediates/package.apk', missing and no known rule to make it
    01:29:34 ninja failed with: exit status 1
    build/core/main.mk:21: recipe for target 'run_soong_ui' failed
    make: *** [run_soong_ui] Error 1
    make: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/aosp/oreo'

    #### make failed to build some targets (25 seconds) ####
```

my idea is to only build those java source from the app level folder to make faster.
is this possible?

thanks!

regards,

SQR

======= update =======

if i run >mma, then >mm.  the build is passing, but it is actually not compiling anything (as the java files are already built?).

if i run >mma, then >mm clean, then >mm, then mm fails to build.

Comment: out/host/linux-x86/bin/aapt is needed by Contacts. So you should use mma firstly.

Comment: @Yong, thanks, please see my post above for update. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can build a single module including all dependencies with `m <module>`.

Example:

```
m Contacts
```

With respect to the error message you are getting: I sometimes get these types of error messages because repositories where not checked out properly and thus files are missing. The sources of `aapt` are located in the `frameworks/base/` repository. You should check whether the git status is valid and that the `frameworks/base/tools/aapt` directory exists.

Comment: hi @Simpl, thanks.  I can build the contact app with dependencies without problem. however, i was looking for a way to build the contact apps without rebuilding the huge amount of dependencies in c++.   is this possible?

Comment: The Build tooling does support incremental build by default. It will however build all dependencies of your module at least once.